# Stop and terminate a context-manager before it begins (but after its __init__)

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager

I have a context manager, subclass of a parent class/context-manager, that I'd like to terminate as soon as possible if some condition is met during the `super().__init__`.

```
class CM:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('__init__')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.condition_depending_on_super_init_result = True  # set to true just to showcase the question
        if self.condition_depending_on_super_init_result: 
            self.__exit__()         # this has no impact: the lines after "with cm:" below are still executed!
            self = None             # why?
    def __enter__(self):
        print('__enter__')
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        print('__exit__')
    def dosomething(self, x):
        print(x)

cm = CM()
print('before with')
with cm:                         # here it should skip the block, not enter it, and not do the next lines
    print('after with')
    cm.dosomething('dosomething')
```

Comment: Context managers don't get to control execution of the `with` body.

Answer (score 1):

One reasonably obvious workaround is to raise an exception.

```py
import logging  # or whatever


class CMInitException(Exception):
    """
    Exception raised by CM.__init__() if the superclass fails to initialize.
    """
    pass


class CM:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('__init__')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.condition_depending_on_super_init_result = True  # set to true just to showcase the question
        if self.condition_depending_on_super_init_result: 
            raise CMInitException("The moon over Redmond is not 3/4 full waxing")

    def __enter__(self):
        print('__enter__')
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        print('__exit__')
    def dosomething(self, x):
        print(x)

try:
    cm = CM()
    print('before with')
    with cm:
        print('after with')
        cm.dosomething('dosomething')
except CMInitException as e:
    logging.warning(e)
```

Comment: I swear I made this up. I do _not_ have access to Microsoft source code.

Comment: Haha! Nice solution @tripleee! I initially wanted to avoid an extra `try` / `except` statement, do you see a solution that allows to "nip `cm` in the bud" so that `with cm:` returns immediately and don't execute inner lines?

Comment: If `cm` is not initialized you can't do `with cm:`

Comment: when entering `with ...:`, `__enter__()` is executed, is it possible, at this moment, to immediately skip the whole block inside the `with`?

Comment: You can similarly raise an exception at any other point if there is another situation where you want to force the caller to give up.

Comment: Yes @tripleee but I mean without raising an exception. So it seems that context-managers do not have control about if we should continue or not the execution flow of the `with:` body, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65089526/stop-and-terminate-a-context-manager-before-it-begins-but-after-its-init/65089727?noredirect=1#comment115072246_65089526)? Or is possible?

Comment: I don't think it's possible without an exception, no.